# Telerik RadGrid Winforms Excel Like Filtering for page wise

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I want to use excel like filter in radgrid winforms but I need to load the filter records as page wise. The problem is I have nearly 100k records in my grid and excel like filter loads all the values of all pages so that it affects performance. How to load the filter in ragrid winforms as page wise? If I have 50 records in 1st page it should load only 50 records in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [page](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/filtering/setting-filters-programmatically-(simple-descriptors)).

It will help you to achieve the solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but already we had seen that page. Could you please suggest any other solution?